# Semantic-UI - Links / A Tags / URLs Inside Semantic Ui Dropdown Menu Do Not Work

Tags: html, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-5, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am working with Semantic UI in a rails project and wanted to create a dropdown menu with items that would link to other view pages. Most of the problems i've seen with the dropdown stemmed from users not initializing the dropdown menu which I was able to do.

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="ui floating dropdown button">
    Course<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">

      <% @topics.each { |topic|  %>
        <a class="item" href="articles/<%= topic.id %>">
          <span class="text"> <%= topic.name %></span>
        </a>
      <% } %>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Different things i've tried:

- Creating a separate hardcoded links / a tags like `<a href="articles/4">` outside of the dropdown menu. This creates a working link and directs me to the article show view page with the id of 4.
- Changed the wrapping 's class as `"ui floating dropdown item"` as well

I've also looked up other users' posts that shows they have the same exact problem. But when i try their solution, my dropdown menu items still do not work and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Here are their posts:

- https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3234
- https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/453

The two most important things seem to be:

1. Not putting the dropdown class definition as part of an anchor tag (inserting an anchor tag inside an anchor tag in the dropdown menu)
2. Not surrounding each anchor tags with their own `<div class="items">` tags but to integrate them into one line like `<a class="item" href="#"> # </a>`

Can anyone help me understand what i might be overlooking? Let me know if i left out any critical information, would love to update the post with the relevant data right away, thank you!

Comment: Have you added the javascript part ?

Comment: Hey Weedoze, i figured out what the problem was and ill post the answer really soon, thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more and more research, I came to the conclusion that the links were not working in my semantic-ui dropdown menu because of some code, most likely Javascript, that i had inserted before.

Of course, i ruled this way out of the realm of possibility because there was no way i would forget about such code but i decided to go through all of my .js files just in case.

Lo and behold, i had a jQuery selector `return false` when a `.item` was being clicked...

I felt really silly and i didnt want to believe it at first but if you're having this problem and you've checked everything else like i have, it's ***probably*** your javascript!